# All...either usage

Tags: grammar

"All my heroes are either dead or in prison."
Does it mean X=dead Y=in prison X+Y= all my heroes.
or Does it mean that some are dead and some are in prison?

Answer (score 1):

It's the former. If it were the latter, it would mean that some are neither dead nor in prison, which would then clash with "all."

Comment: agreed with what you said

Answer (score 1):

[Either...or](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/either-or) implies a strictly limited choice of only two options for "all my heroes".

So (strictly speaking) part of them are dead, part of them are jailed, and the two parts make up 100% of the heroes. **(X=dead, Y=in prison, and X+Y="all my heroes".)**

But that's out of context. In a comical context, one could easily say something like, "All my heroes are either dead or in prison. Except Lancelot, who managed to run away, and Merlin, who went nuts."

Comment: sounds reasonable to me. sometimes the language usage changes thru time